# Finding MLE of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and $\sigma^2$, where $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0,\beta_1,...,\beta_p)^T$

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, maximum-likelihood

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + ... + \beta_px_{ip} + \epsilon_i, i = 1,2,\ldots,n$ 
where $ \epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are iid.

In this case, I am trying to find the MLE of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and $\sigma^2$, where $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0,\beta_1,...,\beta_p)^\top$.

I am aware that to find MLE of a simple linear regression, I could find the Log-likelihood, before differentiating it by $\frac{dL}{d\beta_0}$ and $\frac{dL}{d\beta_1}$ and equating them to $0$ to find $\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1}$ and  $\hat{\sigma^2}$.

By extending the method for finding MLE of simple linear regression, I tried the following method:

$\ell(\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2)= \log(P(y|\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2))
=-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{n}{2}\log(\sigma^2)-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum^n_{i=1}(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_{i1}- \ldots -\beta_px_{ip})^2$

However, I am stuck as when I try to differentiate the log-likelihood w.r.t. $\beta_0, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_p$.
Am I on the right track? How am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: have you come across matrix calculus? This will not resolve all your question [matrix calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), but it will help you understand the steps. Additional you can write your LL as 
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2}\log(\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\beta}\mathbf{X})^{T}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\beta}\mathbf{X})
$$
then you will take a derivative w.r.t. to the vector $\mathbf{\beta}$. Plus this goes through the steps as well [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mlr-mle)